# Add random String to ArrayList from another Array

Tags: java, android

Trying to populate my `ListView` with random strings, but it populates with the same value everytime I click on a button same string is being chosen. Like `Dog`, `Dog`, `Dog` ...

Can anyone please give me a hint on that?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
    String[] list2 = {"Bubbles", "Goldie",
            "Dog", "Fins", "Dory"};
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    int randomNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Random rand = new Random();
        randomNum = rand.nextInt(list2.length);

        Button add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_button);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                list1.add(list2[randomNum]);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: debug, debug, debug. run that step by step through a debugged, and see what is being called, in what sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the random number generation in the `onCreate()` method.

If you want a new random index generated each time you click the button, you need to put it in the `onClickListener` instead:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    list1.add(list2[rand.nextInt(list2.length)]);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When `OnCreate()` is being called, `randomNum` is being assigned:

```
randomNum = rand.nextInt(list2.length);
```

It does not change in runtime.

Change

```
list1.add(list2[randomNum]);
```

to

```
list1.add(list2[rand.nextInt(list2.length)]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is in here.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    list1.add(list2[randomNum]);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`randomNum` will never change with your current implementation. A random number is only generated once when your activity is created.

You can either add `randomNum = rand.nextInt(list2.length);` to your `onClick` method, or have `list1.add(list2[rand.nextInt(list2.length)]);`